# Solve security issue parsing xml using SAX parser

Tags: java, android, xml, security, saxparser

I have an android app, in which user can enter any xml source url to parse. My app then parses the xml(if valid) and displays results.

The issue is, **if the user enters an untrusted xml source url**, the app and/or the device might be effected.

What are the **best ways to identify risk and prevent exploit**.

With my research I found that enabling FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING and disabling expansion might help. But can anyone tell me what it is, and how do I achieve it.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use a schema to validate the XML content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After researching, I found this. I hope this would solve my problem.

To enable FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING

```
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
spf.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
```

Disable DTDs

```
spf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", true);
```

Comment: Did this actually work? I am getting an exception when doing this.

Comment: @digitizedx Were you able to get out of exception. I am getting javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl

Comment: @ArpitGarg. No. OWASP suggest some alternatives. So I just followed https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#JAXP_DocumentBuilderFactory.2C_SAXParserFactory_and_DOM4J

Answer (score 2):

- For **SAX** and **DOM** parsers, disallowing DTD should be sufficient as dcanh121 noted.

  factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", true);
- For **StAX** parser:

  factory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_REPLACING_ENTITY_REFERENCES, false);